# osgWidget label within frame won't trigger the callback

Tags: c++, callback, event-handling, openscenegraph

Here's my problem
I'm new to osg and I'm trying to create something like a dropdown list by adding osgWidget::Labels to a osgWidget::Box and then setting this same box as a osgWidget::Frame's window and all this works fine until the part where my callback "labelClicked" is never actually triggered once I click the label.

I tried adding this callback to other widgets such as an input and even the actual frame where I keep the box with the labels, and both worked fine.

Here's the functions that I use to add labels to my dropdown list:

```
osgWidget::Label* DropdownInput::createLabel(const std::string& l, unsigned int size) {

osgWidget::Label* label = new osgWidget::Label("", "");

label->setFont("fonts/Vera.ttf");
label->setFontSize(size);
label->setFontColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
label->setLabel(l);

return label;
}

void DropdownInput::addLabel(string text){

osg::ref_ptr<osgWidget::Label> label1 = createLabel(text,15);

label1->setName(text);
label1->setPadding(2.0f);
label1->setColor(1,1,1, 1);
label1->setSize(300.0f, 40);

label1->setImage( "img.png" );
label1->addCallback( new osgWidget::Callback(&DropdownInput::labelClicked, this, osgWidget::EVENT_MOUSE_PUSH) );



dropdownContent.push_back(label1); //list where I store the labels for flitering purposes
this->dropdownBox->addWidget(label1);

}
```

and the callback:

```
bool DropdownInput::labelClicked(osgWidget::Event& ev) { 
    cout<<"label clicked!"<<endl;
    return true;
}
```

Already tried to place the labels inside a box inside a frame and adding the callback to this frame instead, and then adding it to the main box but not only did it not resize correctly but also caused lag when filtering the labels which is not an option.
Also tried with other types of events like mouse over and such and still no answer from the label.

I was asked to avoid using other UI libraries, so if possible I would prefer osgWidget based solutions.

So, now I'm a bit lost, any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you didn't find my explanation to be comprehensible enough don't hesitate telling me since it's my first time posting here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For labels you should first add the push event to the label event mask:

```
label->addEventMask(osgWidget::EVENT_MOUSE_PUSH);
```

Otherwise `label->canMousePush()` will return `false` and the callback will never be called.

Comment: Thank you so much! You just saved me from a lot trouble   (I don't have enough reputation to upvote though :( )